# Aligning elements inside a LinearLayout taking half screen space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four elements inside a linear layout.

I want to align them in such a way that `classALabel` & `classBLabel` are aligned right next to each other side by side taking half-half width of the screen.

And `classA` & `classB` also aligned right next to each other side by side taking half-half width of the screen BUT below `classALabel` & `classBLabel`.

Below is what I have tried so far, but this isn’t working as I want. It is just showing all four elements side by side giving each 25% of screen space.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ClassALayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ClassLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classALabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/classALabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/classALabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classBLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/classA"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/classBLabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/classBLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you have put all of your views into a single linear layout with horizontal orientation. Since there are 4 views with weight=1 the screen is divided into 4 equal parts.

The below code should help you achieve what you want.

The ClassALayout Linear Layout is the parent layout which further contains two child linear layouts - LabelContainer Linear Layout and ClassContainer Linear Layout. The ClassContainer layout is below the LabelContainer layout because the parent layout has vertical orientation.Both child layouts contain 2 textview.
The label textviews are above the class textviews and all of them take up 50% of the screen space.

```
<LinearLayout                  
android:id="@+id/ClassALayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height"
android:layout_below="@+id/ClassLayout"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LabelContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classALabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/classALabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classBLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/classBLabel" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ClassContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classB"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution for you is this

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/ClassALayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height"
android:layout_below="@+id/ClassLayout"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classALabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/classALabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classBLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/classBLabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classB"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</TableRow>
```

or if you really want to use a `LinearLayout` you need to use a parent `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` with 2 child linear layout with `android:orientation="horizontal"` but remember that the more child layouts you have with relative sizes (meaning the use of `android:layout_weight`) the more taxing on the system .

Or you could use a relative layout but you cannot use `android:layout_weight`

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you have created only one LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. All views which you will put inside of this layout will be in the same row.

All you have to do is create parent layout, it could be linear layout, with vertical orientation, and then inside of this layout create 2 separate linear layouts with horizontal orientation and put 2 text views in each one.

Answer (score 0):

Its a quick and dirty solution but it will give you what you want:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/classALabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="classALabel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/classBLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ClassBLabel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/classA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="ClassA"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/classB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ClassB"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Half of ScreenSize.